# Passing data through XAML into VB

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, custom-controls

ORIGINAL (Solved by Clemens):

I have code (below) where I am trying to pass a parameter through XAML into VB.  This gives it an error code **"** *'tabText' property was already registered by 'customTabPanel'* **"** and I am not sure what I should do here as this is my first attempt takling this  problem

NEW:

This still doesn't pass the text through properly and I have no idea why.  Any help will be appreciated.

VB:

```
Public Class customTabPanel
Inherits Grid
Dim workSpaceAssociation As Grid
Public ReadOnly TextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("tabText", GetType(String), GetType(customTabPanel), New PropertyMetadata(String.Empty))
Public Property tabText() As String
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(TextProperty), String)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        SetValue(TextProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
Sub New()
    Me.Height = 20
    Me.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(27, 27, 28))
    Dim textBlock As New TextBlock
    textBlock.Foreground = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
    textBlock.Text = tabText
    textBlock.Width = 100
    textBlock.Padding = New Thickness(10, 0, 25, 0)
    Dim closeWorkspace As New TextBlock
    closeWorkspace.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right
    closeWorkspace.Text = ""
    closeWorkspace.Foreground = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
    closeWorkspace.Height = 15
    closeWorkspace.Width = 15
    closeWorkspace.FontFamily = New FontFamily("Segoe UI Symbol")
    'add'
    Me.Children.Add(textBlock)
    Me.Children.Add(closeWorkspace)
    Me.Width = textBlock.Width
    Me.Margin = New Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0)
    Me.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left
End Sub
Sub SetText(ByVal t As String)
    tabText = t
End Sub
Function GetText() As String
    Return tabText
End Function
End Class
```

XAML:

```
<ThisIsAwsome:customTabPanel tabText="Start Screen" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency property field has to be declared as `Shared`:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly TextProperty As DependencyProperty = ...
```

---

In order to get notified about updated property values, you would also have to register a PropertyChangedCallback with the property's metadata:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly TextProperty As DependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "tabText", GetType(String), GetType(customTabPanel),
         New PropertyMetadata(
             String.Empty, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf TabTextChanged)))
```

In the `TabTextChanged` callback you would set your TextBlock's Text property (no idea though if it's valid VB):

```
Private Shared Sub TabTextChanged(
    ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Dim panel As customTabPanel = CType(d, customTabPanel)
        panel.textBlock.Text = CType(e.NewValue, String)
End Sub
```

You'll find a detailed explanation in the [Custom Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot.  Unfortunately it does not actually show the text passed through.  I have added more code that might help